# 64 bit update package on Windows Server 2003 x64 gives error "Not a valid win32 application"

Tags: windows-server-2003

I'm trying to run the following update package: WindowsServer2003.WindowsXP-KB2536276-v2-x64-ENU.exe downloaded from here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms11-043 but when I run it I get the error " is not a valid Win32 application."

I am running it on Windows Server 2003 R2 x64 and made sure I downloaded the correct file for my OS.

I am installing this file manually (along with others) because I do not have access to the MS Updates site as I am in a locked down environment. The company update server is not accessible until this  machine is joined to the domain. IT won't join it to the domain until this and other patches are installed... so patches must be downloaded and installed manually.

Answer (score 1):

The Affected OS list doesn't mention Windows Server 2003 R2.  Windows 2003 != Windows 2003 R2

Comment: I agree 2003 is not hte same as 2003 R2, however I don't believe they are different enough to warrant separate treatment by MS in regards to security bulletins. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin, where Server 2003 R2 is not available as an option when searching for security bulletins by product/technology.